# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification Found versions 25.2.0, 25.0.2

Tags: java, android, xml, android-appcompat

this is my Error poping out and whole project depends on this

[image: this is my Error poping out and whole project depends on this]

**My Gradle code is given below**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Safeer.Ahmad.MusicXtreme"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 34
        versionName "1.1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
  //  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:+'
    compile 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'bz.tsung.android:objectify:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.3.0'
    compile 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.0'
    compile 'me.priyesh:chroma:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.12'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.lantouzi.wheelview:library:1.1.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
}
```

[see it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U2E3.png)

**How did this error happens?**
i updated android studio and gradle and build tools as i want everything latest and this error pops out and i've tried every possible thing to solve it but failed. Just this error is unsolved rest my app is ready.

**Current gradle is 3.3 and android studio is 2.3.1 with latest 26 support library appcompat**

Comment: change this  **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'**  to **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'**

Comment: i have tried it buth nothing :(

Comment: Maybe this library is causing the issue because it uses old version of support library **compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'**

Comment: The root of errors is from Android support library thing.. v7.. nothing is fixing this creepy error :(
Tried your way but still nothing

Comment: You have not added support v7 lib?

Comment: Added it.. see it in photo posted

Comment: Hey you are only changing version for appcompat-v7 you need to either keep all support lib to 25.2.0 or 25.3.1

Comment: tell me plz how to change it all to 25.3.1?

Comment: Replace 25.2.0 in your gradle file with 25.3.1

Comment: i have done this but for v7 its not working.

Comment: use gradlew app:dependencies to check the dependencies tree.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you declared different versions of the support library for different modules. For example:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
```

First, you need to change these to the same version. I have found that it is easier to keep version numbers in sync by adding a visible to the project's ext block. If I have time I'll add a link here. In the meantime, you should do some research.

I am not sure where the compile gets version 25.0.2 since you do not seem to declared this explicitly. It is possible that one of your other dependencies uses a that version of the support library.

Comment: changing of v4 25.2.0 to 25.3.1 fix the warnings but for v7 nothing is working.

Comment: @SafeerAhmad if you want help with your updated version, you need to post a new question. This one has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]
Replace your dependencies with below code and check if its working or not

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:renderscript:25.2.0'
compile 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'bz.tsung.android:objectify:1.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recycler-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.3.0'
compile 'tyrantgit:explosionfield:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.0'
compile 'me.priyesh:chroma:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.12'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
compile 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
compile 'com.lantouzi.wheelview:library:1.1.2'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
}
```

Comment: i have pasted this code and posting the error in terms of photo.

Comment: Replace all 25.2.0 with 25.3.1 and check

Comment: Hey @SafeerAhmad I tried with same dependencies and it worked with my updated answer. Try it and check if it works for you

Answer (score -1):

Update the `appcompat-v7` line. The latest appcompat version is

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

If updating all your dependencies to `25.3.1` doesn't work, click "Analyze" -> "Analyze dependencies..." in Android Studio and update your question with the output.

Comment: This will not fix the problem, as that is not the same version as is used by the other dependencies. Using the latest version is a good idea, but it needs to be done for *all* dependencies from the Android Support Library, and this project is using at least five of them, perhaps more.

Comment: That's what I implied, yes :)

Comment: Error:(33, 0) startup failed:
build file 'D:\Safeer\WORKING NOW\Music\app\build.gradle': 33: expecting ''', found '\r' @ line 33, column 53.
   id.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
                                 ^

1 error

<a href="openFile:D:\Safeer\WORKING NOW\Musicr\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: You need to enclose the dependency in single quotes

Comment: so you are saying to convert to latest version for every support library? i have tried to fix it by using 25.3.1.. for V4 all warnings are gone but for v7 its still the same :(

Comment: Yes, update all versions to `25.3.1` (and make sure that you actually have those versions installed by performing an update check in the SDK Manager).

Comment: @Miraduro The error message is very clear: All support libraries must use the same version.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in the version specified in your gradle files, like lets say, package x as dependency version1 and package k as same dependency version 1.5, gradle will throw that error. Consider using the exclude keyword to exclude a version dependency and set a shared one.

Also though not recommended instead of specifying the exact versions, replace the versions with a +.Example replace all seeded numbers with,

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Make sense?

Comment: all support library must conform to same version

Comment: here is forum on exclude https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119

Comment: transitive dependencies are the problem here

Comment: Thanks let me try it too.

Comment: check updated answer , try using + for dependency, this is saying grab me the latest version

Comment: Still not working :( stucked at v7 changed everything to 25.3.1 and 25.2.0 and 25.0.2.. still by bAD

Comment: did u used +, for versions instead

Comment: changed all v7 versions to +

Comment: this includes every support library in v7

Comment: also try excluding from compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5, libraries such that as their own support version already